# Is there a way in typescript to type a string as JSON string and specify the parsed objects type?

Tags: typescript

```
{
  key1: "{\"key2\": \"123\", \"key3\": \"ABC\"}"
}
```

In the above object the value of key1 is a JSON string that needs to be parsed.

Is there a way in typescript to type the parsed value of a JSON string like below?

```
type hypothetical{
  key1: jsonString<{
    key2: number;
    key3: string;
  }>;
}
```

Comment: `"123"` is a string, not a number.

Comment: What type is `jsonString<T>` supposed to be?  I’m having a hard time understanding if you want the compiler to parse JSON string literal types to object types or to serialize object types to JSON string literal types, or something else.

Comment: Either way I wonder if you really plan to have a JSON string that is statically known to the compiler without just doing the parsing beforehand.  Like, what’s the use case here? It’s a neat exercise to work on JSON parsing at the type level but I’m skeptical about its utility.

Comment: I want to assert that the value of `key1` will be a valid json string which on parsing will have `key2` and `key3` as properties with respective datatypes.

Comment: @jcalz `const parsedObj = JSON.parse(aboveObj.key1)` parsedObj should implicitly have type `{key2: number; key3: string;}` without having to specify `const parsedObj:{key2: number; key3: string;} = JSON.parse(aboveObj.key1)`.
`aboveObj` is returned by an api

Comment: Generally speaking, values returned by an API are only available at runtime and not in your source code.  Unless the literal string `'{"key2": "123", "key3": "ABC"}'` appears in your TypeScript source code, there's absolutely no hope of divining the type `{key2: string, key3: string}` from it (again, `"123"` is a string.  `123` is a number).  One of us is confused about how your app is going to work; I'm willing to believe that it's me, so could you spell out exactly how the TypeScript compiler will know what the value returned by the API will be?

Comment: In case anyone cares, you can write a buggy and fragile JSON parser in the compiler and use it to convert the above literal into type `{key2: "123", key3: "ABC"}`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1yGOw).  But again, there's no point in doing this if the string literal comes from an API at runtime.

Comment: the typescript compiler won't know the value but the type of the value returned by the api like this `const response: hypothetical = await fetch("https://example.com/someEndpoint")`

Comment: Okay, uh, mayyybe I understand what you're asking for.  Is it something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9E71N)?  If so I could write up an answer explaining how it could work, but I really don't see this as any safer or ergonomic than the normal way of doing it when you specify the type at the point when you parse the JSON... it's certainly more complex than the normal way.  Can you articulate the use case whereby this is a net benefit?

Comment: yep...this works, but I don't yet understand how it works. It is not necessarily a net benefit. I was looking for a way to specify a single type for the object returned by the api instead of specifying a second subType for `key1` after parsing. My types are auto generated from openApi spec so the type for `key1` would simply be string and the type of the object after parsing would need manual intervention

Comment: If you want me to write up an answer post explaining how it works I can do so.  Would you be inclined to accept such an answer or am I still missing something about your goal?

Comment: your solution above works perfectly fine...I just don't understand the typescript generics well. If you can explain that in an answer it'd be great

Comment: Ugh I wrote out a whole answer and then my browser crashed before I could save it.  Oh well, second time's a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is some sort of generic type `JsonSerialized<T>`, which is a special kind of `string` that the compiler knows will produce a value of type `T` when parsed with [the `JSON.parse()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).  That is, it will behave like this:

```
interface MyType {
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean
}

function example(jsonString: JsonSerialized<MyType>) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); // MyType
  console.log(obj.a.toUpperCase()) // okay
  console.log(obj.b.toFixed(1)) // okay
  obj.d // compiler error, MyType has no d property
}
```

Here the compiler knows that `obj` is of `MyType`, and thus it will warn you if you try to access an unknown property like `d` (as opposed to the "anything-goes" behavior you'd see if `obj` were of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), which is what `JSON.parse()` normally produces).

Compare this to the "standard" approach:

```
function example(jsonString: string) {
  const obj: MyType = JSON.parse(jsonString); // MyType
  console.log(obj.a.toUpperCase()) // okay
  console.log(obj.b.toFixed(1)) // okay
  obj.d // compiler error, MyType has no d property
}
```

Here you have to explicitly tell the compiler to treat `obj` as a value of type `MyType`... that's not really type safe, since the compiler wouldn't complain if you annotated `obj` as being some other type `NotMyType`.

---

Now, you're not trying to get the compiler to actually look at a string and figure out what `T` to use in `JsonSerialized<T>`.  That string won't even exist until runtime anyway.  In example code we can use a [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) string, but that won't be available to the compiler in your actual use case.  So we'll have to *tell* it:

```
async function getResponse() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    key1: '{"a":"foo", "b": 123, "c": true}' as JsonSerialized<MyType>
  });
}
```

That `as JsonSerialzed<MyType>` is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), and you'll have to do that with whatever code receives the relevant `string`.  So we haven't improved the type safety over the normal way of parsing JSON; we've just moved the safety hole to slightly before calling `JSON.parse()` instead of slightly after it.

---

Now we have to actually define `JsonSerialized<T>`. Ideally we'd like to just use `string` and have `JsonSerialized<T>` be a [*nominal type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) that the compiler treats as if it were distinct from `string` even though it's just a `string` at runtime.  But the following won't work:

```
// doesn't work
type JsonSerialized<T> = string;
```

TypeScript has a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), not a nominal one.  The fact that `JsonSerialized<MyType>` and `JsonSerialized<YourType>` and `string` are all three different *names* doesn't mean they are three different *types*.  The compiler (mostly) only cares about the *structure* of a type, and all three of those are just `string`.  This can lead to unpleasant inference problems; see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) for more info.

Instead we can use a trick to simulate nominal types, called "branding".  See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) for more information.  It looks like this:

```
type JsonSerialized<T> = string & {
  __json_seralized: T;
}
```

Here we are giving a fictitious `__json_serialized` property of type `T` to `JsonSerialized<T>`.  Now there is a compile-time structural difference between `JsonSerialized<MyType>` and `JsonSerialized<YourType>` and `string`.  But we're just pretending; at runtime the strings will not have any such `__json_serialized` property.  It's a phantom property just to help the compiler keep track of types.

---

Okay, we're almost done.  All that's left is to let the compiler know that `JSON.parse(x)` should produce a value of type `T` when `x` is of type `JsonSerialized<T>`.  We *could* locally fork the TypeScript library to modify its [`JSON` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3b2fa50a14a380e25639cea579e33d9b452d63ed/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1052-L1074), but that would be terrible to maintain.  Luckily you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add a call signature to `JSON.parse()` to your local code base without modifying the upstream library.  Like this:

```
interface JSON {
  parse<T>(text: JsonSerialized<T>): T;
}
```

(if your code is in a module then you will need to wrap that with a [`declare global {}` block](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to access the global `JSON` interface).

---

All right, let's try it out:

```
type JsonSerialized<T> = string & {
  __json_seralized: T;
}    
interface JSON {
  parse<T>(text: JsonSerialized<T>): T;
}
    
interface MyType {
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean
}    
function example(jsonString: JsonSerialized<MyType>) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); // MyType
  console.log(obj.a.toUpperCase()) // okay
  console.log(obj.b.toFixed(1)) // okay
  obj.d // compiler error, MyType has no d property
}

async function getResponse() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    key1: '{"a":"foo", "b": 123, "c": true}' as JsonSerialized<MyType>
  });
}

async function doSomething() {
  const resp = await getResponse();
  example(resp.key1);
}

doSomething(); // FOO, 123.0
```

Hooray, it all works!

---

But, let's compare this to the standard way of doing this:

```
interface MyType {
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean
}

async function getResponse() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    key1: '{"a":"foo", "b": 123, "c": true}'
  });
}

function example(jsonString: string) {
  const obj: MyType = JSON.parse(jsonString); // MyType
  console.log(obj.a.toUpperCase()) // okay
  console.log(obj.b.toFixed(1)) // okay
  obj.d // compiler error, MyType has no d property
}

async function doSomething() {
  const resp = await getResponse();
  example(resp.key1);
}

doSomething(); // FOO, 123.0
```

I don't really see much of a benefit of the proposed method over the normal method.  They are both somewhat unsafe and can't deal with an unexpected JSON string.  They both require someone to manually tell the compiler what type the deserialized object is, it's just that one does it before `JSON.parse()` and the other does it after.  The `JsonSerialized<T>` code is more complicated.

The only reason why I could imagine wanting this is to put an abstraction barrier or function boundary between the code that *receives* the JSON string, and the code that *parses* that string.  But that's a weird place to put a barrier.  The only reasonable thing one can do with a JSON string is to parse it, and so whoever receives it might as well immediately parse it and hand back the deserialized object instead of the JSON string.  And if that's the case, then the difference between `const obj = JSON.parse(str) as MyType` and `const obj = JSON.parse(str as JsonSerialized<MyType>)` is negligible.

Maybe you have a use case that makes `JsonSerialized<T>` a better choice, but I'd advise you (and anyone else who finds this question and answer) to think carefully about whether that is really true before proceeding.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYGUICcCWBDANpgLwgBMAeAFQD4oBeKOYLJAcygDIoBvAWACgooAfUEArREkFwMeQiQBcUcgG4+AXz59MSYBgBm2AMbQYKAPIA5LnwFhs6KRUoAKHQA9gC+MjRYZRMlQAlArKahq8mtp6htAAsiDk4NA8-FDYCgxMzAA01lAARgpIAK4AtvkYuakGCvkICLgQ2EhhEby6xUgGwJjIUBCu2KVgjU5i3oxazJ7iPjj4-qTxiZCUgVbVyAxQCPkitLBm5gB0tvYQY7OTLIFKUAD091DLSXkGWw0Qx7gIzE67ImO2GOwAQAFUwJB0ABhbBSJyBdaPHYAa2wIDeH0a31+-z2x3yIIQADFMK4SE4AIyIh5PBBojGpAHHYi0qDvYaYRrofrodAIdDZZ4JJJQAAWcKgSAQUFZYH5UNArT4cJAXSgHS6PT6zAgwAAShA4GAthd1ikBOg9cV0EgoAAFfmlTBSY5WxC4ABuFwtAigKIgIEpCgA5JwAETYcNycO6erhoXh-LRqCUgBMAGZEwYU4xihBVCG0nBYLMMPNZGQXqs8qpbsreKr1Zrur07cQECgEKU9WKpgiNgJ3khtu6wAdsAB3bCYYBQXUGo0mkdmlSpAZDEYXMfHANB+u8dRtDtdnvAPssBF3ZHE0ymIXpjPHAAM4T4j0e4SQQyXMVgBjwAhBylH9jT-cwBVKPAAHV0Q2cI-SgLQdHQfQjGFFZkjyRD0noa4cmwv1CilMoKkFQih1qepGmaQij0IpsDA1TpWx1PVDWNU0B19RCrWAG07UdbsXS+d0Gm9JweMQ-1A2DKAw0jaNY3jRNkwUR9s1zdB80LCioDrNdEPo1IBBbbU7Q3YZRnGVB8IyfDzT04dtgBBRq2gOgTAsU47HhGyUAc68nncpysS+H4-mZYFQQhKFYXhGlkXpdFQpHT4cUi-FCVBUlyWIKlErpBk9OZVlkQ5MAuQwXl+UFDDRQlEtpVlKB5QQRVGSMhC-UY5itTbWVO27Xt+0cky-WcucxwnadZ3ndily4g9pP6QYrO3Jdd1k5a-SPRDCJPYbz1GoKoFve9U0zF9a26j97nCVQgA)